# what is the very last element of a 4x4 transformation matrix for?

Tags: opengl, matrix, transformation

while its a similar value to its neighbour - Z translation (and I wont say if thats above or to the left for fear of sparking a religious war!) and it only seems to change when the Z translation value changes, however the value is not quite the same

Normally I just see either this value ignored or just a 1 in all the tutorials I've seen

Can someone explain exactly what this last element does ?

Comment: the question I asked wasn't answered by the "duplicate" as far as I can see - can you explain why you consider it a duplicate ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value is for [Homogeneous Coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). Using homogeneous coordinates makes it possible to use things like quaternions and projection matrices. The last entire row is actually for dealing with homogeneous coordinates.

Essentially, the coordinates transformed by a 4x4 matrix will be a 4x1 vector, with (X,Y,Z,W) components. The final values of (X,Y,Z) are determined by taking the homogeneous coordinates and dividing them by W.

E.g. 1

```
[4,2,1,2] is transformed to [2,1,0.5,1]
```

Wherein the final XYZ coordinates are then (2,1,0.5). Again, this is useful for dealing with quaternions and creating projection matrices.

E.g 2

```
Projection of point p onto the plane
 orthoganal to the Z axis and distance d
 from the 'camera'.

               .p
     d   |               <- given
c--------|------------>Z
         |

     d   |.p'
c--------|       <- desired projection
         |

p' = (d / p.z) * p

x' = dx / z
z' = d

d 0 0 0 * x = dx -> dx / z
0 d 0 0   y   dy    dy / z
0 0 d 0   z   dz       d
0 0 1 0   1    z       1
```

In the case of a projection matrix, homogeneous coordinates allow the projection of scene geometry onto a plane (the screen).

Comment: thanks that gives me a clue in what direction to take my further research