# Normalizing a homogeneous 3d point

Tags: mathematics, shaders, hlsl, vertex

As I've seen corruption in geometry, why is it a bad idea to normalize a homogeneous (divide by w) the vertex position returned from vertex shader?

**Update**

Vertex shader:

```
// float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
output.pos = mul( mvpMatrix, float4(input.pos, 1) );
output.pos /= output.pos.w; // this line causes the visual corruption below
```

Three images as I move to the right of a sphere in wireframe. As I get closer the geometry starts corrupting. It seems the geometry immediately around the camera gets the most corrupt. [image: geometry corruption]

Comment: A bad idea for what exactly? The fragment shader? What sort of corruption? [Dividing by W is how projection matrices work](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90589/what-is-the-very-last-element-of-a-4x4-transformation-matrix-for/90597#90597)

Comment: @XGundam05 agreed.  Please elaborate on what issue you encountered.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to make out exactly what you mean, but it sounds like you are dividing the vertex position by `w` as part of your computation in your vertex shader. This is incorrect, the division by `w` is actually done for you by the graphics processor. Consider the standard transformations here:

[image]
(Original image from: http://www.c-jump.com/bcc/common/Talk3/Math/Matrices/Matrices.html
)

If you were to divide by `w` yourself it would just end up happening twice which will naturally yield strange results. The vertex shader can safely write the vertex position as the result of

```
gl_Position = Proj * View * Model * in_vertex;
```

EDIT:
My answer is in the context of OpenGL, but the same would apply to DirectX.

Comment: Looks like this person also saw corruption: http://www.piratehearts.com/blog/2010/02/13/oh-w-divide-you-so-crazy/ "I also discovered today that trying to do the W divide in the vertex shader is bad and wrong and bad. Interpolating (Z/W) is not the same as interpolating Z and W separately and then dividing."  -- its possible OpenGL is using the W value to compute something (e.g., depth) before it normalizes the point.